# Path Variable and workbooks.add into path directory

Tags: excel, vba, path

Is there a way to use the workbooks.add function and have this workbook immediately created in a specified directory?

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Name2
```

What happens is that the second line above is supposed to go to a Dropbox folder, however, the workbooks.add automatically gets created in My Documents, which overrides the second line of code because the Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path then becomes My Documents.  When the original file is opened that houses the macro, it is in the folder where that code would obtain should obtain correct path if the workbooks.add was absent.

Comment: `Thisworkbook.Path` will give you the path for the workbook which contains the macro - if that's where you want to save the new workbook then use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the filepath beforehand?

Something like this (thanks for the feedback in the comment):

```
String path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "/" & Name2
```